# The VM Instances UI changed, no way to SSH and lists image, snapshot and disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

The compute engine, VM Instances view stopped showing usual options. I tried this across chrome and firefox including incognito mode, no change in the behaviour. Its same when checked on a different system too. Our usual way to console was through the SSH button on this page, we didn't save SSH files locally!.. now blocked.

The way the VM Instances page shows up now:

[image: VM Instances page]

The error message with  tracking number:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 2):

There's an ongoing incident:
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/developers-console/19003

You can check the status of the console and other google cloud services here:
https://status.cloud.google.com/